# SugarCRM change the line item label in Quote

Tags: sugarcrm

How to change the label, in line item in Quote in sugarCRM?

and how to remove some of the fields?

just like from:

```
Quantity    Quoted Line Item        Mft Num Tax Class   Cost    List    Unit Price  Total Discount
```

to

```
Quantity    Item Name       Mft Num     Cost        Unit Price  Total
```

Comment: What version? What screen? Is it a specific view, or the printed PDF?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Based on the label names specified by you, it appears that you're using Sugar 7.9 or newer. Therefore this answer is written with that version in mind.*

**Changing Labels**

Labels can be changed in *Administration -> Studio -> Products -> Labels*.

Make sure the selection on the top right is set to "All Labels".

You probably also have to change the Labels in *Administration -> Studio -> Quotes -> Labels*

If that should also fail and Quick Repair & Rebuild doesn't help, you could try a bit more invasive way:
Replace the label-IDs (LBL_...) of your choice in the custom file mentioned in the next step with the text you want to be displayed. However, such text would then be displayed for *all* languages.

**Removing Fields**

If you want to remove fields you probably have to do it via code. Do this by copying 
`modules/Products/clients/base/views/quote-data-group-list/quote-data-group-list.php` to `custom/modules/Products/clients/base/views/quote-data-group-list/quote-data-group-list.php` (you'll probably have to create the folders first)

Then remove the fields that you don't want to see in `custom/modules/Products/clients/base/views/quote-data-group-list/quote-data-group-list.php`

After your changes make sure to check the syntax of the file with `php -l custom/modules/Products/clients/base/views/quote-data-group-list/quote-data-group-list.php`, so that you don't brick your Sugar by accident.

Start a *Quick Repair & Rebuild* in *Administration -> Repair* to load your changes.

If something went horribly wrong and Sugar won't load after, just delete the custom quote-data-group-list.php *and* the contents of the cache/ folder and Sugar should load again.